# iOS 12.3.1 (16F203) Support Files needed

Tags: ios, xcode

I downloaded the newest iOS update to my iPhone 7+ and got this message

[image]

When it happened to me before on the 12.1 update [I used this answer to add the file to the DeviceSupport folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52815254/4833705).

I've been looking around on SO and I can't find anything that supports 12.3.1, the closest I found is 12.2. I tried [this answer](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/115290) which led to [this answer](https://github.com/xushuduo/Xcode-iOS-Developer-Disk-Image/issues/7#issuecomment-481993590) but it didn't work for me:

[image]

**Does anyone know where the 12.3.1 update is at?**

Comment: Please Check hopefully its help in feature : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52815254/8526454

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I was facing this issue as well. The trick is to do the following:

For example you get next error:
[image: device support error]

1. Create a new empty folder named `12.3.1 (16F203)` (note: replace the parenthesis value with your device code) in the `DeviceSupport` folder `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/` and copy-paste the contents from the next most recent support folder (12.3).
2. Quit XCode, unplug your device, and re-open your project in XCode.
3. Once XCode loads, connect your device again and select your device as the target and run the app. At this stage, Xcode will notify that it processing the build folder. Do not cancel this process and let it do its thing.

After completing these steps, my phone was able to run my app. Hope this works for you as well.

Comment: You was correct, the key was to add whatever was in the parenthesis next to the folder name. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Glad you identified the missing step :)

Answer (score 11):

Here is the correct way of handling support errors from `Xcode`. All you have to do is add support to `Xcode's DeviceSupport` folder.

Open this link, extract the zip and copy the folder. https://github.com/amritsubedi/iOS-Developer-Disk-Image/blob/master/12.3.1.16E227.zip

**NOTE: A new version of iOS 13.0 beta recently released. If your Xcode throws iOS 13.0 support files needed, then click the link below:**

https://github.com/amritsubedi/iOS-Developer-Disk-Image/blob/master/13.0.zip

Then, go to `Applications -> Xcode`. Right-click and open Show Package Contents. Then, paste to `Contents -> Developer -> Platforms -> iPhoneOS.platform -> DeviceSupport` and restart `Xcode`.

Note: If you have a problem with any other version of iOS, then download the right iOS Developer Disk Image and paste it in the above-mentioned folder.

This will work. 
[Press this to visually see the path.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCXqf.png)

Comment: still freezing. Bad solution. Just removing warning text. Slow as before.

Comment: @Vladimir It might be due to the missing device code. Rename 12.3.1 with 12.3.1 (your device code) and re-open Xcode. If this doesn't work, it has nothing to do with Xcode's device support because it is all Xcode needs for device support.

Comment: @AmritSubedi what was your xcode version? I am trying with Xcode 9.4.1. Will this work with xcode 9.4.1?

Comment: @gypsicoder It will work with Xcode 9.4.1 if it supports the device version. Otherwise, you have to update Xcode. I am using Xcode version 10.1.

Answer (score 4):

Resolving with old Xcode 10 or later, or problem got resolved without downloading new Xcode. The following iOS versions 12.3 and 12.3.1.

You have to do the following steps.

1. You have to download the zipped file from the link : 
        https://drive.google.com/file/d/1we9n9vjRBK8sui8mkYUeBDqzPwwdt9i8/view
2. Unzip the folder.
3. You have to go following the path: `Macintosh SSD⁩ ▸ ⁨Applications⁩ ▸ ⁨Xcode10 ▸ ⁨Contents⁩ ▸ ⁨Developer⁩ ▸ ⁨Platforms⁩ ▸ ⁨iPhoneOS.platform`
           ⁩Or you go with the following steps, type the following:
   Open terminal. `cd /Applications/Xcode10.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport`
4. Press Enter and then type `open .`
5. The finder is open.
6. Now Copy the downloaded "12.3.1 (16E227)" folder.
7. Paste the folder in finder.
8. Relaunch the Xcode.

It works perfectly

Comment: we have following the all steps but my Xcode shows the simulator in 12.2 please give me more details on this error removed.

Comment: Downloading binaries from someone's Google drive? No thanks. Do you know where the official binaries can be found?

Comment: still freezing. Bad solution. Just removing warning text. Slow as before.

Answer (score -3):

You need to update your Xcode too, every time you do an OS update on your device, you need to update Xcode also.

Comment: You don’t need to update Xcode, read the links to the answers in my question. I don’t want to go through the update process, adding the support files is faster.