# Can't find iOS 12.3.1 simulator

Tags: xcode, ios12

I'm trying to install iOS 12.3.1 simulator but I'm not able to find it.

[image]

I did follow some [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56366563/ios-12-3-1-16f203-support-files-needed) like creating a folder for 12.3.1 and 12.3 and copying contents from 12.2 to them but that's not the case.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to release notes, iOS 12.3 (and the future iOS 12.4) uses the iOS 12.2 SDK. Thus the latest available simulator is 12.2.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios_ipados_release_notes/ios_12_3_release_notes

iOS Supporting Files are not related to simulators. They are downloaded from your device. Try to remove created folders and plug your device in with USB to speed up the transfer. Also make sure Xcode is up to date.